# Finding the number of items in inventory each week from sales data

Tags: r, aggregate, aggregate-functions, week-number

I am aggregating data by week and need to find the number of items in inventory for each week. I have the date sold(Contract Date) and the date the item was added to the inventory. I also have a list of the items still in inventory that have not been sold. This needs to be done for both new and used items.

I am looking for the R equivalent of this excel formula

=COUNTIFS(New!$A$2:$A$43254,">="&A3,New!$O$2:$O$43254,"<"&WeeklyData!A2)+COUNTIF(NewInventory!$M$2:$M$939,"<"&A3)

Column A in New is the Contract Date or date of the sale.
Column O in New is the date the sold item was added to inventory
Column N in NewInventory is the date the unsold items were added to inventory

Column A in Weekly data is the first day of the week (m/d/y)

In order to perform the calculations by week, I added a column with the number of the week and the year (52/2022 would be the last week of this year)

```
WeeklyVariableData$New$WeekYearSale <- strftime(WeeklyVariableData$New$'Contract Date', format = "%U/%Y")
WeeklyVariableData$New$WeekYearInv.x <- strftime(WeeklyVariableData$New$'DateAdded', format = "%U/%Y")
```

I need a full list of all the items that have been sold at some point and that are currently in the inventory. Here Key is basically the barcode, but it is a unique number for each item.

```
NewWeeklyData <-
  full_join(WeeklyVariableData$New,
            WeeklyVariableData$NewInventory %>% dplyr::select(Key, DateAdded, WeekYearInv.y), 
            by = "Key")
NewWeeklyData
```

Now I want to group by the Week Year tag that I made at the beginning and find the number of observations where the sale occurs during or after that week and the date added to inventory is before or during that week.
**This is the trouble spot, but I don't know how to fix it. It is returning weekly numbers that are way too low.**

```
NCInv <- NewWeeklyData %>%
  group_by(WeekYearSale) %>%
  summarize(NCInvSold = sum(WeekYearSale >= WeekYearInv.x, na.rm = TRUE))

NCInv
```

Now I want to find the number of items that are in stock each week for items that are yet to be sold.

```
NCNotSoldInv <- NewWeeklyData %>%
  group_by(WeekYearInv.y) %>%
  summarize(NCNotSoldbyWeek = n_distinct(Key, na.rm = FALSE))

NCNotSoldInv
```

Then I tried to join these together and change missing values to 0 so the two columns can be added together in the next step.

```
NCInv <- NCInv %>%
  left_join(NCNotSoldInv, by = c("WeekYearSale" = "WeekYearInv.y"))
NCInv <- as.data.frame(NCInv)
NCInv[is.na(NCInv)] = 0
NCInv
```

Here I want to add the two columns I have created together to find the total number of items that are in stock each week. Including items on the sales list and items on the current inventory list.

```
NCInv$NCInv <- NCInv$NCInvSold + NCInv$NCNotSoldbyWeek
NCInv
```

Here is the dput for the first 4 rows:

```
structure(list(`Contract Date` = structure(c(1577836800, 1577836800, 
1577836800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    ModelYear = c(2020, 2020, 2019), Make = c("Honda", "Subaru", 
    "Volkswagen"), Key = c("16H6419*5FNYF6H58LB019602", "15SD7429*4S4BTALCXL3156024", 
    "15VD4787*3VWC57BU3KM253219"), DateAdded = structure(c(18179, 
    18262, 18176), class = "Date"), WeekYearSale = c("52/2019", 
    "52/2019", "52/2019"), WeekYearInv.x = c("40/2019", "00/2020", 
    "40/2019")), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please share a few rows of sample input as well as the desired output. Preferably using `dput()` so it is copy/pasteable in valid R syntax and includes all relevant class and structure info.

Comment: Please don't put data in a comment, it's better to [edit] your question and place data in a code block. Thanks!

Comment: Okay just added the data to the end of the post

Comment: @GregorThomas does that data help?